# How do you transfer files onto the Hadoop FS (HDFS) on WIndows cmdline without Cygwin?

Tags: windows, hadoop

I have zero experience with Hadoop, but suddenly have to use it at work with Spark on Windows. My question, which has been asked a few times here, but I never could quite get the syntax for what I need, is this. I'm trying to transfer a simple file called:

`gensortText.txt` which let's say is at `c:\gensortText.txt`

I know you can use `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal`. I've tried these things:

1. `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\gensortText.txt hdfs://0.0.0.0:19000`

   > ERROR: Relative path in absolute URI.
2. `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\gensortOutText.txt \tmp\hadoop-Administrator\dfs`

   > ERROR: copyFromLocal: `tmphadoop-Administratordfs': No such file or directory

and a number of other variations with `hdfs:` and using the `tmp` directory which all returned similar errors.

I have hadoop in `c:\deploy` as suggested in the Hadoop2Windows guide (which works and allowed me to run Hadoop. I can access the WebGui and all that). Hadoop has created my new HDFS at `c:\temp`. Please someone help me figure out how to transfer files into the system. It can even be manually if that's possible, but that doesn't seem to work as it doesn't show up in the Web GUI when I go to "Utilities->Browse the Filesystem". Nothing shows up there actually.

Can someone please help. Any information that's relevant I can provide, but I'm so new to this I don't really know what would be helpful. I think it's just my syntax for the cmdline tool. Can someone give me a concrete example of how to use hadoop -fs copyFromLocal or another simple way to do this? Sorry for my ignorance on the subject, and thanks for any help

Comment: hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\gensortOutText.txt \tmp\hadoop-Administrator\dfs

you need to hold a mirror at corner to rotate slashes

hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:/gensortOutText.txt /tmp/hadoop-Administrator/dfs

Comment: thanks Burak that was correct. I also had an issue with my hadoop install being in a bad state or something. I restarted the server and was able to work again

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run hadoop commands on Windows you need to have **winutils** installed and visible to hadoop process.